# Update Preview is showing loading

Tags: lightning

I have created simple lightning application. But on click of update preview its showing "Loading" and nothing id getting displayed.

FirstApplication.app

```
<aura:application extends="ltng:outApp" >
    <c:FirstApplicationComponent> </c:FirstApplicationComponent>
</aura:application>
```

FirstApplicationComponent.cmp

```
<aura:component 
                implements="force:appHostable,
                            flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,
                            flexipage:availableForRecordHome,
                            force:hasRecordId,
                            forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,
                            force:lightningQuickAction" 
                access="global" >
    <ui:inputtext label="Full Name" aura:id="EnterFullName" placeholder="FirstName,LastName"/>
    <ui:button aura:id="SubmitButton" label="Submit" press="{!c.getinfo}"/>
    <ui:outputtext aura:id="outputvalue" value=""/>
</aura:component>
```

FirstApplicationController.js

```
({
    getinfo : function(component) {
        var FullName = component.find("EnterFullName").get("v.value");
        var OutName = component.find("outputvalue");
        OutName.set("v.value",FullName);
    }
})
```

[image]

Comment: why are you using ltng:out

Comment: Got it because of ltng:out its showing loading i replaced it with force:slds